# what is Community Wiki and purpose of it?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Is there any benefit to tick "community wiki" when post answer? I have just noticed that option and would like to get detailed information.

I have researched for answer of my question but did not get exact and satisfied answer.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/community-wiki/info

Comment: Isn't the explanation in the [community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/community-wiki/info) tag info clear enough?

Comment: okay , I have searched through "http://meta.stackoverflow.com/".. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community-wiki is a flag  that "lowers the barrier for editing and prevents any rep gain/loss from voting."